# Best way to show a collection of images/media on a mobile site?

Tags: mobile-web, carousel

I am currently working on a mobile version of my website (separate from the desktop one) and I need to display a collection of images on a particular page.

On the Desktop version, I had used a carousel to display them however I can see carousel's as being hard to use on a phone even if I integrate swipe gestures.

So, in your opinion what is the best way to display a collection of images that would normally be presented through a carousel?

**This to note:**

- There are no descriptions or other text involved - just images
- All the images are of the same size and aspect ratio

Comment: How many images need to be displayed on this page ? Is this number fixed ? Does it have a maximum ? Also, are these images the main content of this page (in terms of page estate taken by the various displayed elements) ?

Comment: These images are not the main focus of the page, but they're still pretty important. There are a maximum of 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would implement a 3rd party tool like [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/). iPhone, iPad, Android, Blackberry 6 and Desktop all supported. Take a look at their [video demo](http://vimeo.com/24124859).

---

## ***What is it?***

> PhotoSwipe is a FREE HTML/CSS/JavaScript based image gallery specifically targeting mobile devices.

## ***Who is it for?***

> Developers and designers requiring an interactive image gallery on their mobile website with the look and feel of a native app.

## ***Why use it?***

> PhotoSwipe provides your visitors with a familiar and intuitive interface allowing them to interact with images on your mobile website.

---

## ***Screenshots***

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]

Comment: seems like a cool implementation. Will definitely give this a shot.

Comment: @KevinPei - Yea, it does. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like one full-width image below which put thumbnails, say, in the grid 3 images per row. Default display first one, change displayed image as user picks other thumb.

However, it depends on a context. What's been written above is good for images of hotel rooms or images of users.